# Javascript image viewer not working in internet explorer

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, client-side

I have made a similar kind of image viewer mentioned in below site for my website.
http://www.javascriptkit.com/script/script2/backbox/
The image viewer is working fine in Chrome but not working in Internet Exlporer;
I have not given my website details for security reasons but you view the issue by copy pasting below link in Chrome and Internet Explorer.
http://www.javascriptkit.com/script/script2/backbox/

**Click the Image in above link and see the error in internet explorer & see the same in other browser to see its working condition...**
**PFB snap shot**

Could any one of you tell why is not working in internet explorer ?

Error Msg from IE F12 devolper tools console area is :

> SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'replace': object is
>   null or undefined  effects.js, line 1 character 1747
>
> effects.js =
>   http://www.javascriptkit.com/script/script2/backbox/js/effects.js

If you need sample js files, please get that from http://www.javascriptkit.com/script/script2/backbox/backboxfiles.zip

HTML used is;

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="backbox.css" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/prototype.compressed.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/scriptaculous.js?load=effects"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/lightbox.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/dhtmlHistory.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/customsignsheader.js"></script>

<div onclick="dhtmlHistory.add('location1',{message: 'backbox'});countdown()">
<a href="images/babyhand.jpg" rel="lightbox[slide]" caption="A Bunch of Grapes">
<img src="images/sunset.jpg" alt="lime" width="400" height="300" border="0" /></a>
</div>

<a href="images/desert.jpg" rel="lightbox[slide]" caption="Sunflower"></a>
<a href="images/beech.jpg" rel="lightbox[slide]" caption="Dolphin"></a>
<a href="images/lime.jpg" rel="lightbox[slide]" caption="Waterfall"></a>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/customsignsfooter.js"></script>
```

[image]

Comment: Is it logging any errors in IE

Comment: please copy paste this link and see the output http://www.javascriptkit.com/script/script2/backbox/
Click on the image

Comment: Works fine for me in IE8

Comment: @ManseUK : Its not working in my IE8; Do i need to setup anything else? Pls find below error:
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'replace': object is null or undefined effects.js, line 1 character 1747
http://www.javascriptkit.com/script/script2/backbox/js/effects.js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

regarding about your concern why this occurs in IE and not in chrome, that's because of this condition `if(/MSIE/.test(navigator.userAgent)` which is true when your browser is IE

for correcting the issue, as you said in a comment you can add a 'undefined' condition.
just replace this line:

```
if(/MSIE/.test(navigator.userAgent)){Element.setStyle(_10,{filter:Element.getStyle(_10,"filter").replace(/alpha\([^\)]*\)/gi,"")+"alpha(opacity="+_11*100+")"});}
```

with:

```
if(/MSIE/.test(navigator.userAgent)){var filterStyle=Element.getStyle(_10,"filter");if(typeof(filterStyle)!="undefined"){Element.setStyle(_10,{filter:filterStyle.replace(/alpha\([^\)]*\)/gi,"")+"alpha(opacity="+_11*100+")"});}}
```

and this line:

```
if(/MSIE/.test(navigator.userAgent)){Element.setStyle(_10,{filter:Element.getStyle(_10,"filter").replace(/alpha\([^\)]*\)/gi,"")});}
```

with:

```
if(/MSIE/.test(navigator.userAgent)){var filterStyle=Element.getStyle(_10,"filter");if(typeof(filterStyle)!="undefined"){Element.setStyle(_10,{filter:filterStyle.replace(/alpha\([^\)]*\)/gi,"")});}}
```

in the *effects.js* file

Answer (score 1):

Open developer tools in IE (press F12) and click the "Console" tab. You should be able to see in there that there's an error with the effects.js script :

```
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'replace': object is null or undefined 
effects.js, line 1 character 1747
```

That should at least give you somewhere to start looking.

...and if you're that lazy, the actual line of code it's failing on is this :

```
Element.getStyle(_10,"filter").replace(/alpha\([^\)]*\)/gi,"")
```

The getStyle call is clearly returning null, so subsequently calling replace will fail.

Comment: i could not find any problem with replace function; Please find full js file here & let me the problem please; http://www.javascriptkit.com/script/script2/backbox/js/effects.js
pls reply as 50 bounts going to expire in few days...

Comment: You're not looking at the right thing. I'm not wading through a morass of obfuscated code to find the issue, but you should be able to easily see that the problem is with this call : Element.getStyle(_10,"filter") - this is obviously returning null so subsequently calling replace on it fails.

Comment: why is this not occuring in chrome ? If that is returning null Then Can We have Some null If condition to replace Some value. . What it should return ? Also please let me know why is this working fine in other browsers ?

Comment: @adhocgeek Just for further investigations: http://jsbeautifier.org/?without-codemirror ;).

Answer (score 1):

Internet Explorer does not currently have full HTML5 support.  Any manipulation of HTML5 related tags or elements will therefore fail.  It is worth trying to include the [html5shiv](http://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/) library, which tricks IE into believing these tags exist.